# How does this cypher query select a random node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a project that uses Node.js, Cypher, and Neo4j. The project's front end occasionally needs to **QUICKLY** pull a random user. I have seen this query on the internet:

```
MATCH (n:User) WHERE rand() < 0.1 RETURN n LIMIT 21
```

but I have no idea what this does. It seems pretty fast, but I would like to understand it. A breakdown of what I know:

```
MATCH    | Match some nodes
(n:User) | Let's call this node n, and it has to be of type User
WHERE    | Specify conditions for node match
rand()   | Return a random number from 0 to 0.9999...
<        | Less than
0.1      | ??
RETURN   | Give back the matched node(s)
n        | Our node(s)
LIMIT 21 | Don't return more than 21 nodes
```

What does the `rand()` and `0.1` do? Does it somehow limit the potential nodes to return?

If this helps, I have around 10,000 nodes

Comment: Did you look up the Cypher docs and read the description of `rand()` (which is pretty much the same as any random-number generator in other languages)?

Comment: Why the downvote? As far as I know, `rand()` returns a random number from 0 to 0.99999... but how does that return a random user?

Comment: It's just a simple eval in the where clause. So, with each node, you end up with a random number that's compared. The downvotes are probably because it's so easy to just run that query and see the results (even just returning the random number along with the node, to see what comes back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question already states, a `WHERE` clause specifies the conditions for a `MATCH` to succeed. So, `WHERE rand() < 0.1` means the `MATCH` has a 10% probability of succeeding.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the `0.1` part that none of the comments explained!